# Why do these two different zetas produce the same value?

Tags: special-functions, number-theory

```
Zeta[-13] == Zeta[-1] == -1/12
```

Why do these two different zetas produce the same value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to understand the issue, we should provide the underlying definitions. 
*Mathematica* helps in verifying appropriate relations and definitions. The main functional equation relating Riemann's zeta function $\zeta\;$, to Euler's $\Gamma\;$, established in Riemann's famous paper *[Über die Anzahl der Primzahlen unter einer gegebener Grösse](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Riemann_Hypothesis/1859_manuscript/zeta.pdf)* (1859, English translation [here](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Riemann_Hypothesis/1859_manuscript/EZeta.pdf)), where he formulated the Riemann hypothesis, can be simply written and evaluated with the system:

```
Through @ { HoldForm, FullSimplify}[
             Zeta[z] == 2^z Pi^(z - 1) Sin[Pi z/2] Gamma[1 - z] Zeta[1 - z]]//
Column // TraditionalForm
```

$$\begin{align*}&\zeta(z)=2^z\pi^{-1+z}\Gamma(1-z)\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\zeta(1-z)\\
&\text{True}\end{align*}$$
Similarly we can exploit the definition of `Zeta` for `Re[z] > 1` (see `SumConvergence[1/n^z, n]`):

```
Sum[ 1/n^z, {n, Infinity}] == Defer[ Sum[ 1/n^z, {n, Infinity}]] == 
Defer[Product[ 1/(1 - Prime[i]^-z), {i, Infinity}]] // TraditionalForm
```

$$\zeta(z)=\sum_{n}^\infty \frac1{n^z}=\prod_{i}^\infty \frac1{1-(p_i)^{-z}}$$

```
List @@ (2^z Pi^(z - 1) Sin[Pi z/2] Gamma[1 - z] Zeta[1 - z])
```

$$\left\{2^z,\pi^{z-1},\Gamma(1-z),\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right),\zeta(1-z)\right\}$$

Let's find adequate values:

```
Table[{2^z, Pi^(z - 1), Sin[Pi z/2], Gamma[1 - z], Zeta[1 - z]},
      {z, {-1, -13}}] // Column
```

$$\begin{align*}
&\left\{\frac12,\frac1{\pi^2},-1,1,\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right\}\\
&\left\{\frac1{8192},\frac1{\pi^{14}},-1,6227020800,\frac{2\pi^{14}}{18243225}\right\}
\end{align*}$$

For positive even integers, `Zeta` evaluates to exact values, and one can calculate them from the above definition, but `Mathematica` can do it too, e.g.:

```
HoldForm[ Sum[ 1/n^14, {n, Infinity}]] == Sum[1/n^14, {n, Infinity}] // TraditionalForm
```

$$\sum_n^\infty \frac1{n^{14}}=\frac{2\pi^{14}}{18243225}$$

Moreover, we have a simple relation between the Euler gamma function and factorial for natural numbers:

```
 FullSimplify[ Gamma[n] == Factorial[n - 1], n ∈ Integers && n > 0]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Finally, one has to check also the rational coefficients of the above formulae:

```
FactorInteger @ { 8192, 18243225, 6227020800} // Column
```

> ```
> {{3, 6}, {5, 2}, {7, 1}, {11, 1}, {13, 1}}
> {{2, 10}, {3, 5}, {5, 2}, {7, 1}, {11, 1}, {13, 1}}
> {{2, 13}}
> ```

Comparison of the factorization results completes our proof. Q.E.D.

**Edit**

There are infinitely many arguments where `Zeta[x]==-1/12`, though  `-13` and `-1` seem to be the only integers among them on the other hand negative odd arguments yield rational values.

```
Reduce[ Zeta[x] == -(1/12) && -1000 < x < 1000, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> x == -13 || x == -1
> ```

Here we add a plot of contours of the real part equal to `-1/12` and the vanishing imaginary part of `Zeta` in the complex plane:

```
ContourPlot[ {Re[Zeta[x + I y]] == -(1/12), Im[Zeta[x + I y]] == 0},
             {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, Evaluated -> True, 
             PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Points of `Zeta[x + I y] == -(1/12)` lie on intersections of the blue and red curves

Answer (score 6):

(This is a math question, not a *Mathematica* question.)

To add to Artes's answer, there is the [well-known(!) identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta/03/01/0001/)

$$\zeta(-n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}B_{n+1}$$

so you might as well ask why

$$\begin{align*}
-\frac12\times B_2&=-\frac1{14}\times B_{14}\\
-\frac12\times \frac16&=-\frac1{14}\times \frac76
\end{align*}$$

A justification for the relationship with the Bernoulli numbers is discussed in many references, e.g. [Edwards's, *Riemann's Zeta Function*](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA12).

Comment: And  `FullSimplify[Zeta[-n] == (-1)^n/(n + 1) BernoulliB[n + 1], 
 n ∈ Integers && n > 0]` returns `True`.

Answer (score 2):

In fact there are lots of `Zeta`s  which produce the same value, e.g. try these:
$\{\zeta(-2), \zeta(-4), \zeta(-6),\ldots ,\zeta(-2n)\}$

```
{Zeta[-2], Zeta[-4], Zeta[-6]}

 (* {0, 0, 0} *)
```

Using `Plot` may shed some light on this:

```
Plot[Zeta[x], {x, -15, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Zeta[-2n] are the trivial zeros.

Comment: I obviously knew that, but my point was the inverse zeta is not a proper function. Zeta[-2n] was just an example. So there are lots(uncountable infinite number) of repeated values for the Zeta function.